# Number word instead of Number using row_number() or any similar function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, row-number

The `row_number()` expression in sql server would return numbers like 1,2,3...

But, I need First, Second , Third.... when I use it on some result set.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help, but you would have to do it for every value you expect.

```
CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id)
  WHEN 1 THEN 'First'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Second'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'Third'
  ELSE CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS VARCHAR)
END
```

You can also prepare a special table containing these values and join on this table so it would be one place only to change things.

Comment: I'm looking for something which is inbuilt and defined by SQL server itself. I can use the way you have suggested, but, its very static and needs to be changed at some place

Comment: No such thing, you have to create your own number table.